# Java NoClassDefFoundError Error

Tags: java, manifest

I wrote the basic code below and saved to a file called pdf.java.

```
package pdf;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class pdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException{
        System.out.println("Hello World2!");
    }

}
```

I then compiled it like this,

```
javac pdf.java -cp core-renderer.jar:iText-2.0.8.jar
```

Which seemed to work as I got a pdf.class file. I then tried to run it with the following command.

```
java pdf
```

And I got the following output,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pdf (wrong name: pdf/pdf)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compiled it so, the pdf.class was generated in current directory. Change it to:

```
javac -cp core-renderer.jar:iText-2.0.8.jar -d . pdf.java
```

Which will generate `pdf.class` in `./pdf` subdirectory. Then run it as follows:

```
java -cp .:core-renderer.jar:iText-2.0.8.jar -d . pdf.java
```

Comment: Hi, for the second command I get - 

Unrecognized option: -d
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Comment: It's a bad copy/past, I think the command meant was `java -cp .:core-renderer.jar:iText-2.0.8.jar pdf.pdf`

Comment: Yes, indeed it was. I corrected it soon after hitting the post button but user201140 got there before me.

Comment: Thanks Hemal and Colin, that does it.

Answer (score 5):

Didn't you mean `java pdf.pdf` as your `pdf` class is in the pdf package ?

If your pdf class is in the pdf package it should be in a pdf directory (as in if your MyClass class is in my.package package, it should be in my/package/ directory).

Either you go into the pdf directory and use the `-d` option `javac -d . pdf` or you go in the parent directory and do javac pdf/pdf.java`

Comment: I don't see a pdf package declaration but you are almost certainly right :)

Comment: Sorry, I reverted it again, it should be as you saw it before now.

Comment: So the problem was the pdf package. You're luky I saw that, because it would have been harder to debug without the package declaration.

Comment: No, once he writes `java pdf.pdf` he will get `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Of course, it needs to be in the pdf directory (as the package says)... `mkdir pdf && mv pdf.java pdf && javac pdf/pdf.java && java pdf.pdf` or `javac -d . pdf.java` would correct it.

Comment: Hi Colin, its not fixed, I'm not sure its the pdf package.

Answer (score 0):

First, since the class is declared as in a package, you have to store it and call it using the package path.

You need to create a directory structure that matches the package structure.  In your case, you need to create a directory called `pdf` and move `pdf.class` into it.

Then you would call with `java pdf.pdf' as pointed out in Colin's answer.

This might be sufficient to run your current sample code, since it doesn't really do much of anything.  Once you get to adding more functionality, you will likely need to include your libraries on the classpath when executing, as described in Richard's answer.

BTW, it is conventional in Java programming to initcap class names, e.g. `Pdf` would be the class name in your example, while `pdf` would be the package name.

Comment: I tried moving pdf.class into a pdf directory and ran java pdf.pdf, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Classpath for compile-time and for run-time are two different things.  However, they are often identical since compilation dependencies are identical as runtime dependencies.  Since your `main()` method throws something defined in `iText-2.0.8.jar` (I think), you sould define your classpath accordingly:

```
java -cp .:iText-2.0.8.jar pdf.pdf
```